# fastest/smallest signed integer type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading about the Fixed width integer types ([cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) ) and come across 
the types `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t`, `int_fast32_t` and `int_least8_t`,
`int_least16_t`, `int_least32_t`,etc. My questions are following

1. What does it mean by saying for example `int_fast32_t` is **fastest** signed integer type (with at least 32 bits )?  Is the more common type `unsigned int` slow?
2. What does it mean by saying for example `int_least32_t` is **smallest** signed integer type?
3. what are the differences between `int_fast32_t`, `int_least32_t` and `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

int_fast32_t means that it is the fastest type of at least 32 bit for the processor. For most processors it is probably a 32 bit int. But imagine a 48 bit processor without a 32 bit add instruction. Keeping everything 48 bits is faster. int_least32_t is the smallest type for the target that can hold 32 bits. On the hypothetical 48 bit processor, there might be a 32 bit data type supported, with library support to implement them. Or int_least32_t might also be 48 bits. int is usually the fastest integer type for the target, but there is no guarantee as to the number of bits you'll get.